# Hiding values ​with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble hiding data with jQuery.

I have several products and a filtering system in jQuery, I would like to hide filters that are not used on a given subpage, in my case, data-power.

I am extracting data that matches .product data-power, but now I don't know how to hide a value that is not listed in my 1200 case. Example:

```js
$('.stat').on('click', function() {
  var $stats = $('.stat:checked');
  var $items = $('.list .product');

  $items.show();
  if ($stats.length == 0)
    return;

  var $vstats = $.map($stats, function(o) {
    return $(o).data('id');
  });

  $stats.each(function() {
    var $stat = $(this);
    $items.filter(function() {

      var $currentitem = $(this).data($stat.data('type'));

      if ($currentitem.toString().indexOf(",") > -1) {
        var $item = $currentitem.split(",");
        var hit = 0;
        $item.forEach(function(m) {
          if ($vstats.indexOf(m) > -1) {
            hit++;
          }
        });

        if (hit > 0) {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }

      } else {
        if ($vstats.indexOf($currentitem) > -1) {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      }

    }).hide();
  })
});


function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

var array = [];

$('.product').each(function(i, e) {
  array.push($(e).data('power'));
});

var unique = array.filter(onlyUnique);

unique.sort();

alert(unique);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="power">
  <h2>power</h2>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
          <input data-id="750" data-type="power" class="stat power" type="checkbox">750        </label>
    <label>
          <input data-id="800" data-type="power" class="stat power" type="checkbox">800        </label>
    <label>
          <input data-id="1200" data-type="power" class="stat power" type="checkbox">1200        </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grill">
      <h2>grill</h2>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
              <input data-id="yes" data-type="grill" class="stat grill" type="checkbox">yes        </label>
        <label>
              <input data-id="no" data-type="grill" class="stat grill" type="checkbox">no        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="list">


  <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 product" data-power="750" data-grill="yes">
    <a href="/href/freh">
      <div class="product-page__container product-container text-center">
        <div class="product-page__name">
          <h2><span class="d-block">Product Name</span> Product 1</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 product" data-power="800" data-grill="yes">
    <a href="/href/freh">
      <div class="product-page__container product-container text-center">
        <div class="product-page__name">
          <h2><span class="d-block">Product Name 2</span> Product 2</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x0atpcz4/1/

Comment: Post the code in the question.... just like the error message told you to do.

Comment: Added code up, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I would select the items you are to filter and grab the values. Then I would grab the filters and see if they exists and remove the ones that do not.

```js
var powers = $('[data-power]').map(function (){  return this.dataset.power; }).get();

$('[data-id]').filter(function () {
  return !powers.includes(this.dataset.id)
}).closest("label").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="power">
  <h2>power</h2>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
          <input data-id="750" data-type="power" class="stat power" type="checkbox">750        </label>
    <label>
          <input data-id="800" data-type="power" class="stat power" type="checkbox">800        </label>
    <label>
          <input data-id="1200" data-type="power" class="stat power" type="checkbox">1200        </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="list">


  <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 product" data-power="750">
    <a href="/href/freh">
      <div class="product-page__container product-container text-center">
        <div class="product-page__name">
          <h2><span class="d-block">Product Name</span> Product 1</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 product" data-power="800">
    <a href="/href/freh">
      <div class="product-page__container product-container text-center">
        <div class="product-page__name">
          <h2><span class="d-block">Product Name 2</span> Product 2</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I have two different filters? I added the code.

Comment: this code did not work

var powers = $('[data-power]').map(function (){  return this.dsds.power; }).get();
var grill = $('[data-grill]').map(function (){  return this.dataset.grill; }).get();

$('[data-id]').filter(function () {
  return !grill.includes(this.dataset.id)
  return !powers.includes(this.dsds.id)
}).closest("label").hide();